# How to achieve 'Only in' condition in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, having

How to achieve 'Only in' condition in oracle?

I have two tables 'PlanPlanSet' and 'ExcludedPlans'. PlanPlanSet contains Plans and the Plan set associated to each plan. I want to fetch all records from PlanPlanSet where having Plan ONLY IN ExcludedPlans.

PlanPlanSet table

```
Plan1 - Planset1
Plan2 - Planset2
Plan3 - Planset3
Plan4 - Planset1
Plan5 - Planset5
```

ExcludedPlans Table

```
Plan1
Plan2
```

Here Planset1 contains Plan1 and Plan4, and Planset2 contains only Plan2. So Planset1 should not be excluded and Planset2 should be excluded.

Something like,

```
select pps.planset 
from PlanPlanSet pps 
 where pps.planNumber only in (select ex.planNumber 
                               from ExcludedPlan ex);
```

Comment: Please can you add the schema of the tables?

Comment: Planset2 contains plan5, why should it be treated different from Planset1?

Comment: @ Mat- Sorry I have edited the values. Now PlanSet2 contains plan2 only

Comment: @Demo its not 'ALSO IN'. I want all Plansets from PlanPlanSet where plan number only in ExcludePlans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want everything from PLANSETS where every plan within that planset is in the list of excluded plans.

Thinking about this relationally you need to join the two tables together and discover where the number of plans on each side is the same. This means we must allow for them to be different implying a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

```
select p.planset
  from plansets p
  left outer join excludedplans e
    on p.plan = e.plan
 group by p.planset
having count(p.plan) = count(e.plan)
```

This assume that PLANSETS is unique on PLANSET and PLAN and that EXCLUDEDPLANS is unique on PLAN. If this assumption is incorrect then you'll need to `count(distinct ...`

If you want all data from PLANSETS then the logic can be put into an analytic function

```
select *
  from ( select p.*
              , count(p.plan) over (partition by p.planset) as planset_ct
              , count(e.plan) over (partition by p.planset) as excluded_ct
           from plansets p
           left outer join excludedplans e
             on p.plan = e.plan
                )
 where planset_ct = excluded_ct
```

Comment: I want everything from PLANSETS where every plan within that planset is in the list of excluded plans.. I am supposed to find only such plansets of which all the plans are present in ExcludedPlans table

Comment: So, we just need to change the `<>` to an `=` then (which I've done). Your sample query only asks for the planset. Do you actually want everything?

Comment: @ben- I want only the planset. I tried changing <> with = , its working fine!! Thanksss!! By the way, is it possible to convert this query in to an Eclipse link query?

Comment: Not a clue I'm sorry @user1940878. It's a pretty simple query so I'd be surprised if it wasn't. I'd give it a go and if you can't get it to work ask another question detailing what you've tried and what results you're getting, what you expected and what the input data is. (If you're doing this the `create table ...` and `insert into ...` statements are more helpful to people so they can copy and paste and create your test tables without having to do any work - you don't want to make it harder to answer your question!)

Comment: @user1940878 Please mark the answer as the correct answer so the user get his reputation points (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) Best regards :)

Comment: I've got some thoughts about that too @Demo - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298/458741.

Answer (score 2):

This is supposed to find only such plansets of which all the plans are present in ExcludedPlans table. In case all the rows for such plansets are desired omit the distinct on the first row and add any columns needed.

```
Select distinct planset
From PlanPlanSet ps1
Where
exists
(
  Select selected.planset
  From
  (
    Select ps2.planset, count(*) ct, sum(decode(ep2.plan, null, 0, 1)) present
    From PlanPlanSet ps2
    Left join ExcludedPlans ep2 on ep2.plan = ps2.plan
    Group by ps2.planset
  ) selected
  Where selected.ct = selected.present and ps1.planset = selected.planset
)
```

If on the contrary only such plansets of which not all the plans are present in ExcludedPlans table should be selected, then change the subquery WHERE condition to selected.all <> selected.present

Comment: Hi, your outer inline view had two WHERE clauses, which was preventing execution. I've modified this. I've also changed the name of the `count(*)` column expression from `all` to `ct`. This is because `all` is a reserved word that you can't use as a name. I hope you don't mind. You can use something like [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=deb753011f14a0b2bec8a5c5ec13679a) to see whether or not your code works before posting (or after!) Your code [now returns the correct result](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=be06852d3dbf406897c0e82a49521a17).

Comment: @Ben I don't mind at all! Thank you for the fiddle link, I'll check it out - in past I used sqlfiddle which did not perform well and now I only respond blindly :( Your solution is nice as it's way more concise. Also using just count() instead of decoding nulls is neat and did not occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns all the records in `PlanPlanSet` which are sets of excluded plans only:

```
select * from PlanPlanSet pss
where not exists
  ( select planname from planPlanSet x
    where x.setname = pss.setname
    minus
    select planname from ExcludedPlans)
/
```

The MINUS operator produces a set of records from the top subquery which don't exist in the bottom subquery. When the result is an empty set the plan set contains only excluded plans. MINUS is not a very fast operation, so this may not be the best approach if you have a large number of records to process. However, it does have the advantage of retrieving columns of `PlanPlanSet`, not just the `setname`.

[LiveSQL demo.](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f1p5mh133duyu8znscpv3vzn7)